# How to replace label on specific page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I am trying to create a Your Story functionality where the users can submit their stories in form of a comment. I've made a standard page with comments functionality, however instead of 'add new comment' label, I would like to have 'submit your story'. How can I alter this label only on that particular site and keep it as it is on other pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>The easy way is to use the [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module.</strike>

Based on your comment, a variation on the code below should work in your template.php file (based on some [code posted on drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/774146#comment-3355890)):

```
function phptemplate_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['links'] && $vars['node']->type == 'page') {
    $vars['links'] = str_replace('Add new comment', t('Submit your story'), $vars['links']);
  }
}
```

Comment: This module works globally, so iw would replace all add new comment labels even where it should stay as it is.